# WordPress meta_query is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem on using `meta_query` in WordPress. the meta_key that iv'e tried is `wpcargo_status` and the value is `Delivered`. The problem is it is still getting the other status. This is what iv'e tried...

```
$wpc_report_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shipment',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array( 
            'key'           => 'status',
            'value'         => 'Delivered',
            'type'          => 'CHAR',
            'compare'       => '=', 
        )
    ),      
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $wpc_report_args );
// The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo get_the_ID().'<br />';
        echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'shipper_name', true).'<br />';
        echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'status', true).'<br />';
    endwhile;
    endif;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

[**On my database**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHc9q.png)

[**Output of my query**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQXcM.png)

Do you have any idea what is wrong with my code?

**Updated**

I already tried this and it is working but I need multiple `meta_query`

```
'meta_key' => 'status',
'meta_value' => 'Delivered', 
'meta_compare' => '=',
```

Comment: print your $the_query and see the meta_query is empty or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iv'e seen that there is no errors on your `WP_Query`. And there is a possible conflict on your query or there is something overriding on it.

1. Deactivate other plugins
2. Theme conflict
3. Check the [parse_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_query) - This hook will execute after WP_Query.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the other plugin is conflict with parse_query.

Comment: Great! glad I helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$wpc_report_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shipment',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'status',
            'value' => 'Delivered',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $wpc_report_args );
```

Type - Default value is 'CHAR'

Answer (score 0):

```
$wpc_report_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shipment',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array( 
            'key'           => 'wpcargo_status',
            'value'         => 'Delivered',
            'type'          => 'CHAR',
            'compare'       => '=', 
        )
    ),      
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $wpc_report_args );
// The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo get_the_ID().'<br />';
        echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'shipper_name', true).'<br />';
        echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'status', true).'<br />';
    endwhile;
    endif;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
```